# Python Class Unexpected Behavior

Tags: python, class

I'm developing a card game in OOP just for practice, and I have some odd behavior in what Ive written so far. . .When I use the clear method to empty the hands, what happens is the individual hands show they are empty, but when I look at hands variable (that shows both hands), they are NOT empty. My question is why, lol? I'll place the code below and results below. . .Thanks for any help in advance.

```
import random

class a:
    my_hand = []
    other_hand = []
    hands = [my_hand, other_hand]

    def h(self):
        for rounds in range(5):
            for hand in a.hands:
                hand.append(rounds)

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(a.my_hand)
        random.shuffle(a.other_hand)

    def clear(self):
        a.my_hand = []
        a.other_hand = []


x = a()
x.h()
x.shuffle()


x.hands
[[1, 0, 4, 2, 3], [3, 4, 2, 0, 1]]

x.clear()
[[1, 0, 4, 2, 3], [3, 4, 2, 0, 1]]

x.my_hand
[]

x.other_hand
[]

x.hands
[[1, 0, 4, 2, 3], [3, 4, 2, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: Part of the code at the end was cut off. It showed x.other_hand was [], then x.hands was [[1, 0, 4, 2, 3], [3, 4, 2, 0, 1]]. Sorry

Answer (score 3):

In your `a` class the `my_hand`, `other_hand` and `hands` variables are all *class* attributes (i.e. *static* attributes), not *instance* attributes.

Also in your `clear` method you re-assign `my_hand` and `other_hand`, but `hands` still references the old `list`s, hence its content doesn't change. If you are using python3 then you should use the `clear()` method of the `list`s: `my_hand.clear()` and `other_hand.clear()`, then `hands` will reference two empty `list`s.
On python2 you should do `del my_hand[:]`.

If you want to assign a *instance* attribute you have to do `self.attribute = value`.
In order to do so the assignment should be placed inside the `__init__` method which is the constructor of the class.

As it currently stands your code, if you create two instances of `a` then they will share the hands, which is probably something you do *not* want.

The correct code would be:

```
import random

class ClassesUseCamelCase(object):
    # if you are using python2 do *not* forget to inherit object.
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_hand = []
        self.other_hand = []
        self.hands = [self.my_hand, self.other_hand]

    def init_hands(self):
        for round in range(5):
            for hand in self.hands:
                hand.append(round)
        # or simpler:
        # for hand in self.hands:
        #     hand.extend(range(5))

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.my_hand)
        random.shuffle(self.other_hand)

    def clear(self):
        self.my_hand.clear()    # or del self.my_hand[:] in python2
        self.other_hand.clear()
```

Sample output using iPython:

```
In [2]: inst = ClassesUseCamelCase()

In [3]: inst.init_hands()

In [4]: inst.shuffle()

In [5]: inst.hands
Out[5]: [[3, 2, 4, 0, 1], [3, 1, 4, 0, 2]]

In [6]: inst.clear()

In [7]: inst.hands
Out[7]: [[], []]
```

Note that it works with more than one instance:

```
In [9]: inst.init_hands()

In [10]: other = ClassesUseCamelCase()

In [11]: other.init_hands()

In [12]: inst.hands, other.hands
Out[12]: ([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]], [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])

In [13]: inst.shuffle(); other.shuffle()
    ...: 

In [14]: inst.hands
Out[14]: [[0, 1, 3, 2, 4], [1, 4, 0, 3, 2]]

In [15]: other.hands
Out[15]: [[1, 4, 2, 0, 3], [1, 4, 3, 2, 0]]
```

your code would have shared the `hands` between the two instances.

---

I'm putting here a bit more explanation on what's happening to avoid writing too many comments.

First of all, in your code the `my_hand` and `other_hand` are *class* attributes. Why does this matter? It matters because class attributes are shared between *instances*:

```
In [1]: class MyClass(object):
   ...:     my_hand = []
   ...:     other_hand = []
   ...:     hands = [my_hand, other_hand]
   ...:     

In [2]: instance_one = MyClass()

In [3]: instance_two = MyClass()

In [4]: instance_one.my_hand.append(1)

In [5]: instance_two.my_hand   # ops!
Out[5]: [1]
```

Calling the `clear` modifies the class attributes and hence all the instances using them. This, *usually*, is something you do *not* want.

Tthe instances do not have any other instance attribute which means that all instances are, in fact, equal; they all act the same and provide the same data. The only difference is their identity. If you are not going to use the identity then having a class and multiple instances is kind of useless because you could have simply used a single object.

If you want the instances to have their own data, independent from the data of other instances, then you have to use instance attributes.

Regarding the `del` statement. As I've already said in the comments `del` has two different uses. The *full* syntax of the statement is:

```
del sequence, of, del_targets
```

Where the "sequence, of, del_targets" is a comma separated list of what I'll call `del_targets`. Depending on the `del_target` the behaviour changes.

If it is an identifer than `del` removes that *reference* from the scope, decrementing the reference count of the object that was referred to by the identifier.

For example:

```
a = b = []
# Now that empty list has two references: a and b
del b    # now it has only one reference: a
print(b)   # This raises a NameError because b doesn't exist anymore
del a      # Now the empty list doesn't have references
```

If an object doesn't have references it is destroyed, so after the `del a` above the empty list will be destroyed by the interpreter.

The target can also be a "subscript", i.e. an expression like `name[key-or-index]` or `name[a:slice]` (or `name[start:stop:step]`).
The slices syntax (the one with colon) is used to specify a range of indexes:

```
In [17]: numbers = list(range(10))  # [0, 1, ..., 9]

In [18]: numbers[::2], numbers[1::2], numbers[2:7:3]
Out[18]: ([0, 2, 4, 6, 8], [1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 5])
```

When using the `del` statement with such an expression python calls the `__delitem__` method of the object, passing in the index or slice. This means that:

```
del numbers[:]
```

Means: delete all the elements of the list `numbers` that correspond to an index in the slice `:`. Since the slice `:` means "all indexes in the sequence" the result is emptying the list. Note that it does *not* remove the reference from the list. It only acts on its elements.

You can obtain the same effect using:

```
numbers[:] = []
```

This tells python to replace the sequence of elements corresponding to the slice `:` with the elements in `[]`. Since `:` means "all elements" and `[]` is empty, the effect is removing all elements from the list.
This syntax calls `list.__setitem__` instead of `list.__delitem__` under the hood, but the result is the same.
However you can also do: `numbers[:] = [2]` and then all the elements of `numbers` will be removed *and* the `2` will be inserted resulting in the list `[2]`.

Both work, however I prefer the `del` syntax because it makes explicit your intent.
When you read:

```
del something[:]
```

You know that the statement is going to delete something. Then you see the subscript `[:]` and you understand that it will remove the elements from `something` and not the reference `something`. However when you see:

```
something[:] = []
```

First you think, okay this is an assignment. Then you see the `[:]` and you understand that you are doing to "overwrite" the contents of the list. Then you look at the right hand side and see `[]`, so we are going to overwrite the elements with an empty list... finally you understand that the statement will simply remove all the elements from the list.

Comment: Yes, you way makes perfect sense. I was basically following an example from a well known Python book. I'm not quite sure why he used class variables.

Comment: Wouldn't using "del self.my_hand[]" etc. completely erase the list? In other words I want to keep the list itself, but make it empty. Or am I wrong about what "del" actually does?

Comment: @ChrisKavanagh Note that it is: `del self.my_hand[:]` note the colon inside the square brackets. `del self.my_hand[]` is a `SyntaxError`. And: no, it would *not* delete the list itself. It will destroy all its elements. The syntax: `del something[slice-or-index]` where `slice-or-index` is a single integer or a slice (i.e. the syntax with colon) removes the corresponding elements from the list. For example `a = [1,2,3]; del a[1]` results in `a == [1, 3]` and afterwards `del a[:]` results in `a == []`. And `a` is *always* the same `list` object.

Comment: Note that in python you *cannot* destroy an object. Doing `del something` only removes a *reference* to an object, the object may still exist if it has other references. For example `a = 1; b = a; del a` the `del a` only reduces the reference count of `1`, it does *not* destroy anything. Last remark: doing `del something[slice-or-index]` is equivalent to writing `something.__delitem__(slice-or-index)`, in the same manner as `something[key]` is equivalent to `something.__getitem__(key)` and `something[key] = value` is `something.__setitem__(key, value)`.

Comment: I understand. Thanks again for helping me learn something new!

Comment: I'm still not sure what the problem is using Class Variables? In other words, I don't understand why you (and others) have pointed this out? I get that it probably would've been easier to use Instance Variables instead, but not exactly why my Class Vars are being mentioned?

Comment: BTW, I'm using 2.7. .If I change my Clear method to a.my_hand[:]=[] and a.other_hand[:]=[], then everything works correctly. I don't understand why it works correctly like this, and not the original way (above)? Am I not still referring to the original hands var as you describe? And yet it seems to work correctly by emptying the hands var when I print it out. I get hands=[[],[]]. So, lol, I'm confused. .And THANKS again for all the help!

Comment: @ChrisKavanagh I've updated my answer putting together most of what I said in the comments and a bit more. I suggest you read a bit from the [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/) of python for more information. Try to read the tutorial and eventually the Language reference for deep details on the language.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This is exactly what I wanted. .I get the basics of OOP, however when I actually started writing code I found I didn't know as much as I thought. Thanks for taking your time to help, it's GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating new empty lists, but `hands` still references the old ones.

You could simply make sure that `hands` references the new empty lists.

```
def clear(self):
    a.my_hand = []
    a.other_hand = []
    a.hands = [a.my_hand, a.other_hand]
```

or you could modify the lists themselves, by removing all elements.

```
def clear(self):
    del a.my_hand[:]
    del a.other_hand[:]
```

FYI, all of your functions are defined as member methods, but your variables are always static. You may want to reference `self` instead of `a`, or make your methods static (with `@staticmethod`).

Comment: I see. Makes perfect sense. .What exactly would making my methods static (with the decorator) actually do?

Answer (score 1):

As an exercise in OOP your code is strange... you are using class members in instance methods. The class instance in methods is named `self`, not `a`. Change your code to

```
 def clear(self):
     self.hand = []
     self.other_hand = []
```

and do the same for other parts of the code.

The problem you are facing is however another: when reassigning `a.hand` and `a.other_hand` you are creating two new empty arrays, thus `a.hands` keeps pointing to the old ones created in `h`.

Changing your code to

```
a.hand[:] = []
a.other_hand[:] = []
```

or to the more idiomatic

```
del a.hand[:]
del a.other_hand[:]
```

will solve that problem.

In Python the `[:]` syntax means "all elements of" and allows also slicing (e.g. `a.hand[1:-1]` is the list of the elemets in `a.hand` except first and last).

Comment: Note that in python3 `list`s have a `clear()` method that is probably more readable then the `del + slicing`.

Comment: It's probably strange because I've never written anything in OOP before now. . .Anyways, thanks for the help.

Comment: Leaving mu code exactly the same, except adding what you suggested a.hand[:]=[] & a.other_hand[:]=[], it worked perfectly. However, as you & others have said, I'm still referring to a.hands which points to the old list in h (as you stated above), so why does it work correctly now? Shouldn't it still not work as in my ex. above & give me [[1, 0, 4, 2, 3], [3, 4, 2, 0, 1]]?